# How to make autofill with range and value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making excels to calculate offers. We have a different kind of "packages" where you have different products. I'm trying to make a button which adds numbers in front of every product we need to offer "full package"

I'm updating these products in every month and adding rows so its really big work to update all "ranges". If I add one row its all gone because everything is +1.

Can I dim somehow these products like...

```
Dim Product1 range (J91)

Product1.value = 1
```

and it adds to number 1 to range witch I dim earlier.

In the future when I need to update I just change from one place all the ranges.

I have like 7 product packages so it is frustrating

```
Sub Package1_3P_4G()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Sheets("Gears").Select
Range("J74:J200").ClearContents


Range("J89").Value = 1 ' Add 1 pc Product1
Range("J90").Value = 1 ' Add 1 pc Product2
Range("J93").Value = 1 ' Add 1 pc Product3
Range("J123").Value = 2 ' Add 2 pc Product4
Range("J124").Value = 1 ' Add 1 pc Product5
Range("J134").Value = 1 ' Add 1 pcProduct6

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean you need to add the value to the existing value of the same range like that `Range("J89").Value = Range("J89").Value+1`

Comment: I want to make dim all product1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ranges first and after that, I want to add values. I have 7 times this kind of code and I want to make it simpler.

Comment: Will you name the range for example "J89" with a named range in your worksheet (Product1) ...? >> so in this case you have 7 named ranges..?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that

```
Sub Test()
Dim e
For Each e In Array("J89", "J90", "J93", "J123", "J124", "J134")
    Sheets("Gears").Range(e) = 1
Next e
End Sub
```